# Is/Are "SAP Data Services" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

I have sentences with software products, such as SAP Business Objects and SAP Data Services. The first one is the name of the company and the name of the family of software applications. The second one is a single application. So they refer to singular things, but they are in plural form. I have doubts whether I should write

> SAP Business Objects provide(s) and SAP Data Services provide(s)

Comment: I hate the guys down-voting a thread without commenting it.

Comment: Me too, I just upvoted the question, so it balances to 0 and doesn't appear as a "bad" question in the search results anymore.

Comment: I would suggest you spend 5-10 minutes reviewing their web sites and literature and use the form they seem to prefer.  (I vaguely recall that SAP is headquartered in Germany, and hence may not adhere to usual US practices.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S. the name of a company or collective entity is treated as singular.  In Britain it can be the other way.  Congress is in session and Parliament are in session.  I would think that if "SAP Data Services" refers to a single application that it would always be singular.

Comment: It's **not** the other way in Britain.  In British English, the speaker is free to choose between singular and plural.  A British speaker's attitude towards an organisation is often revealed by their choice of singular or plural.

Comment: I hadn't noticed singular usage, but that may only be because unlike the plural, which sounds odd to me, the singular doesn't stand out.  I've edited to reflect that it can be that way rather than always is.